# Using apache commons csv: I'm trying to remove a set of records from a List<CSVRecord> but it's not removing all of them/

Tags: java, apache, csv, file-io

I have a list of CSVRecords that I parsed from a file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByASC8p2MeUKZlhTdkxETXV2U3M/view?usp=sharing

using the following code:

```
public static List<CSVRecord> getRecords(File file) throws Exception {
        Reader in = new FileReader(file);
        CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(in, CSVFormat.RFC4180);
        List<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();
        parser.close();
        records.remove(0);
        return records;
    }
```

One of the columns is p(pft), and I'm trying to remove all records where p(pft) is less than 75:
(optStratCsv is the list of csvRecords)

```
           for (int i = 0; i < optStratCsv.size(); i++) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(optStratCsv.get(i).get(14)) < 75) {
                    optStratCsv.remove(i);
                }
            }
```

However, while it should give me a list of about 6000 records, it's giving me a list of about 9000, so clearly I did something wrong. I'd like to figure out what I did wrong.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea. Don't remove the records. Instead make a copy of the records you want and return it. So if record not **p(pft) is less than 75** then copy to temp CSVRecord list. Then return temp.

Each time you remove a record from `optStratCsv`, the size changes in your `for (int i = 0; i < optStratCsv.size(); i++)`. Make sense?

Comment: Ohh I understand. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MishaTsirlin, please accept the answer if this answer helped you. Thanks,

Comment: sorry, I did it now